# Can zparseopts differentiate an argument list that contains '--'?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to use zsh's `zparseopts` builtin to process some shell script arguments.   The argument list may contain `--` to indicate that subsequent values are regular inputs and not options, even if they begin with a hyphen.

When `zparseopts` modifies the argument list, it always removes the double hyphen.  This makes it difficult to determine if an argument starting with a hyphen is an error.

A demonstration; `-a` and `b` are items to be processed:

```
set -- -x -- -a b
print -- $@
# => -x -- -a b

zparseopts -D -a opts -- x
print -- $@
# => -a b
```

In this next invocation, `-a` is an invalid option. But the `zparseopts` result is the same, so there isn't a way to find the error:

```
set -- -x -a b
print -- $@
# => -x -a b

zparseopts -D -a opts -- x
print -- $@
# => -a b
```

This workaround makes a copy of any arguments after a `--`, and later compares the copy with the result from `zparseopts`:

```
items=(${${@[(re)--,-1]}[2,-1]})

zparseopts -D -a opts -- x

if [[ ${#items} -ne ${#@} ]]; then
  items=($@)
  if [[ ${idx::=${items[(i)-*]}} -le ${#items} ]]; then
    print "unknown option: [${items[idx]}] items: [$items]"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

The workaround does what I need, but it seems strange that `zparseopts` doesn't support this directly. Am I missing something?